# Qt & MySQL first connections fail

Tags: mysql, qt

I using Qt 5.15 and I make a standard connection to MySQL

```
bool open() {
 QMutexLocker ml(&fMutex);
 fDatabaseNumber = QString::number(++fDatabaseCounter);
 fSqlDatabase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", fDatabaseNumber);
 fSqlDatabase.setHostName(host);
 fSqlDatabase.setDatabaseName(schema);
 fSqlDatabase.setUserName(username);
 fSqlDatabase.setPassword(password);
 if (!fSqlDatabase.open()) {
     qDebug() << fSqlDatabase.lastError().databaseText();
     return false;
 }
 fQuery = new QSqlQuery(fSqlDatabase);
 return true;
}
```

Like usually :). I call this code from 10 different threads at same time. And always several of the first connections to database fails with "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'" message. All of next connections successful, no mater how many connections threads make at the time. I don't know, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You can't get this message because you don't output an error message in your code. Also you must not share a QSqlDatabase connection over different threads.

Comment: Sorry, now I get output:
`if (!fSqlDatabase.open()) {
     qDebug() << fSqlDatabase.lastError().databaseText();
     return false;
 }
`

I'm not share connection between threads, each thread using it's own database 
`QMutexLocker ml(&fMutex);
 fDatabaseNumber = QString::number(++fDatabaseCounter);
 fSqlDatabase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", fDatabaseNumber);
`

Comment: Did you wrote a small test where you only connect to the database in the main thread and nothing more just to prove if there is no other connection around?

Comment: After some research, I found that the libmysql.dll module was not loaded before the first sql query. When the threads start at the same time, the very first sql query loads libmysql.dll and other threads try to do it independently of each other. At the same time, they interfere with each other. In this case, I am getting an error. Now I just added the declaration of the Database class to void main () {} so that libmysql.dll is loaded in advance and the error disappears.